# Basic Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

[image: Here is the question]

> Given the initial value problem
>    $$x''+4x=0, \qquad x(0)=1, x'(0)=4$$
>   (a) Find the matrix $A$ for which $\begin{bmatrix}x'\\x''\end{bmatrix} = A \begin{bmatrix}x\\x'\end{bmatrix}$.
>   (b) Find the general solution to the differential equation (without the initial condition). You need not express it in real numbers.
>   (c) Find the (unique) solution to the initial value problem. You need not  express it in real numbers.

a) Can someone give me a hint on how I would go about finding the matrix or can someone point me to a similar problem.

b) In this case, I am assuming the general solution would be if the initial conditions were now general.  How does the matrix help with this though?

c) Is this part just asking me to plug in the initial conditions for the general solution?

Comment: where ever you found this problem, look at an example that must be there few pages ahead.

Comment: Hint: $x'=0x+1x'$ and $x''=-4x+0x'$.

Comment: ohhh wow...I see. So how does this help with finding the general solution?

Comment: What is the source of the image?

Answer (score 2):

(b) The general solution is the one satisfies the ODE without considering the initial condition. With the system

$$\vec{x}'=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-4 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \vec{x},$$

You need to find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of the matrix. Let's say, if the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, and eigenvectors are $\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2$. The general solution is then

$$\vec{x}=c_1 e^{\lambda_1 t}\vec{v}_1+c_2 e^{\lambda_2 t}\vec{v}_2. $$

(c) Yes, plugging the initial condition into the general solution would give you the unique solution. In this case

$$\vec{x}(0)=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
4
\end{bmatrix}$$

Note that I used $\vec{x}$ to represent 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
x'
\end{bmatrix}